# Inserting special chars, title splitter

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I am going to do so the webtitle `<title>` is stored in the db, so you can change it without editing file..

I have both the title and a title splitter..

Like this:

```
page.com •
```

the page.com is the title and the • is the splitter

Im having little issue by inserting the splitter, • into the database. I tried insert it as it is, • and by the html code `&bull;`.

The first try by having • is that it turns out as ? in my varchar field,
Second try by having `&bull;` is that in the webtitle it shows also as `&bull;` and not the actual icon/symbol.

How can i fix this and have it accept chars so they dont turn out as ? or ??

Should i use another columntype than varchar maybe?

Comment: u r inserting by some db-editor or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, `title` does not allow [html-entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

imho, you should store as `&bull;`
and only manipulate/convert that into its original character when you outputing HTML

Answer (score 0):

`&bull;` should actually do the trick.
look at your final html code that loaded to the browser.
may be there are some escaping characters

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly the way you should store it. I'm not sure why your browser is not displaying it. I just tested with Mozilla and it work's fine for me.

```
<title>&bull; <- thats a bullet</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Varchar should be fine. . .

When you send your data, or gather it from your DB, are you sending it through anything like htmlspecialchars() ?  Make sure you're actually sending the string, and not a stripped version of the string.